# chain rule for the conditional probability from measure-theoretic point of view

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I am studying the probability theory from Durrett's book. Chapter 5 begins with the discussion on the conditional probability. I have a difficulty in understanding the relationship between measure-theoretic view of conditional expectation and my undergrad-level knowledge of probability.

Assume we have three random variables X, Y, and Z. In the undergrad-level probability course, we had chain rule for the conditional probability which says
$$
P(X\vert Y) = \int P(Z=z\vert Y) P(X\vert Y,Z=z) dz.
$$ 
Now, I am trying to understand the above equality with measure theory tools. Specifically, we can write
$$
P(X\in A \vert \sigma(Y)) = \mathbb{E}[1_{X\in A}\vert \sigma(Y)].
$$
I do not know how to proceed after this point to recover the chain rule for conditional probability. 
I would really appreciate it if you could help me on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
P(X\in A \vert \sigma(Y)) = \mathbb{E}[1_{X\in A}\vert \sigma(Y)]
$$

$$
 \overset{Tower \ Property}{=}E\bigg(\mathbb{E}[1_{X\in A}\vert \sigma(Y)] \bigg|\sigma(Y,Z)\bigg)
$$
Tower property since $\sigma(Y)\subset \sigma(Y,Z)$ [Conditional_expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation)

$$
 \overset{Tower \ Property}{=}E\bigg(\mathbb{E}[1_{X\in A}\vert \sigma(Y,Z) ] \bigg|\sigma(Y)\bigg)
$$
$$=E\bigg(\mathbb{E}[1_{X\in A}\vert (Y,Z) ] \bigg|Y\bigg)
$$

$$
=E\bigg(g(Y,Z) \bigg|Y \bigg)
$$

$$
=\int g(Y,Z=t) f(Z=t|Y) dt 
$$
$$
=\int \mathbb{E}\bigg(1_{X\in A}\vert (Y,Z=t)\bigg) f(Z=t|Y) dt 
$$
$$
=\int P\bigg\{X\in A\vert(Y,Z=t) \bigg\}f(Z=t|Y) dt 
$$

so
$$
P(X\in A \vert \sigma(Y)) =\int P\bigg\{X\in A\vert Y,Z=t \bigg\}f(Z=t|Y) dt
$$
so
$$
P(X\leq x \vert \sigma(Y)) =\int P\bigg\{X\leq x\vert Y,Z=t \bigg\}f(Z=t|Y) dt
$$

if $X$ is continues  you can derive by $x$ in both side and get conditional density.